# Wrong width and height for an ajax inline fancybox containing an image

Tags: jquery, image, size, inline, fancybox

I'm using the fancybox plugin for ajax and images displays and it's working fine when it's a simple scenario. But I'm dealing with quite a tricky issue here.

I have a link which does an ajax call via fancybox, and returns an HTML code with a image within (`<img />` tag). From what I do understand in the fancybox jquery plugin, the HTML is put into a `tmp` var via the `html()` jquery function. After that it calls the `_process_inline()` function in which the width and height of the fancybox box are calculated thanks to the height and width of the `tmp` var content.
The problem is that at this point, when I do a `tmp.find("img").width()` the value is 0 whereas the actual one is 560 pixels.

Does any of you know a solution to solve this problem apart from adding `width` and `height` attributes to the image?

Cheers,
Nicolas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No one ever suggested anything about this, so I decided to go to my first (and only) solution: adding `width` and `height` to the `img` tag.

Works like a charm although I'd have preferred a different solution.